# Unable to update SQL database through python web app

Tags: python, mysql, web-applications

Need help with my python web application. I want the user to be able to update certain fields (I've made some fields hidden). I called updateTrail() in an earlier function, it displays fine. However, when I go to submit the update, my original values stay the same. What's odd to me is that when I debug the form, the updated values that I put in are displayed.

```
 def getUpdate(activities, dogs, restrooms, freepark, open, contact, name):
    """
    Middleware function that will update objects in the database.
    """
    # connect to db
    conn, cursor = getConnectionAndCursor()

    # prepare SQL
    sql = """
    UPDATE hiking
    SET town=%s, region=%s, activities=%s, dogs=%s, restrooms=%s, freepark=%s,open=%s, contact=%s, lat=%s, lng=%s
    WHERE name=%s
    """

    parameters=(activities, dogs, restrooms, freepark, open, contact, name)
    # run the SQL
    cursor.execute(sql, parameters)

    # fetch the results
    data = cursor.fetchall()

    print "<mark> %d row(s) were inserted.</mark>" % cursor.rowcount

    # clean up
    cursor.commit() #commits the changes to the database
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    return data
################################################################################
def updateTrail(name, town, region, activities, dogs, restrooms, freepark, open, contact, lat, lng):
    """
    Allows the user to update a trail of their choosing.
    """
    print'''
    <center>
    <form>
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="%s">

        <input type="hidden" name="town" value="%s">

        <input type="hidden" name="region" value="%s">

        <font color="white"><b>Update Activities</b></font>
        <input type="text" name="activities" value="%s">

        <font color="white"><b>Are Dogs Allowed?</b></font>
        <input type="text" name="dogs" value="%s">

        <font color="white"><b>Are Restrooms Available?</b></font>
        <input type="text" name="restrooms" value="%s">

        <font color="white"><b>Is there free parking?</b></font>
        <input type="text" name="freepark" value="%s">

        <br>

        <font color="white"><b>When is the trail open?</b></font>
        <input type="text" name="open" value="%s">

        <font color="white"><b>Update Phone Number</b></font>
        <input type="text" name="contact" value="%s">

        <input type="hidden" name="lat" value="%s">

        <input type="hidden" name="lng" value="%s">

        <br>

        <input type="submit" name="updateTrail" value="Update Trail Information">
    </form>
    </center>

    ''' % (name, town, region, activities, dogs, restrooms, freepark, open, contact, lat, lng)

    ################################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # get form field data
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    debugFormData(form)

elif 'updateTrail' in form:
    #unpack into python variable
    name = form['form'].value
    town = form['town'].value
    region = form['region'].value
    activities = form['activities'].value
    dogs = form['dogs'].value
    restrooms = form['restrooms'].value
    freepark = form['freepark'].value
    open = form['open'].value
    contact = form['contact'].value
    lat = form['lat'].value
    lng = form['lng'].value

    #update the trail's information to the database
    getUpdate(activities, dogs, restrooms, freepark, open, contact)
```

Comment: You have more `%s` placeholders in the query than parameters you are passing with the query..

Comment: @alecxe I've been working on this for so long I didn't even notice that! so thank you, I fixed that, but it is still not updating.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't "name = form['form'].value" be "name = form['name'].value"?

Comment: AH I didn't notice how many errors I had on this haha, thank you for pointing that out! However, it did not fix my issue.

Comment: Have you tried to see if there are any warnings being generated via the fetchwarnings method?  Also, have you tried printing out your parameters to make sure they are the values you expect?  And if they are, have you inserted the parameters into your query and ran it directly in a mysql shell to make sure the results are what you expect?  Those steps would help narrow down the possibilities.